# read RFID tags from browser on Android

Tags: browser, android, nfc

Is it possible to access the NFC chip and scan a RFID tag from within a webpage displayed in the browser (Chrome or Firefox) on Android? Preferably in JavaScript, so we can put the data read from the tag into a web form and send it to the server.

I found some React Native Libraries that are capable of reading data from RFID tags, but I'm wondering if it's the right language for the job? I have no idea about React native, but I don't think I can just run it on a webpage, or can I?

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about the right thing? NFC & RFID tags are physical devices, are you thinking of QR codes?

Comment: Yes I'm talking about RFID chips embedded in IDs. We need a set of data from the RFIDs and the most conveniant way would be to get the data with a smartphone. The only way to collect the data is through the web browser.

Comment: OK, I get you now

Comment: Why don't you code a script to read the tags and deliver the data. Then trought JS you go and read that data and parse it to the server?

Comment: What would this script look like? The only thing I can think of is to write an Android app and store the data locally, and then read it with JS and put it into the HTML form. Is this what you meant? Or are there other ways to run scripts on Android?

Comment: I found an article about the 'Scripting Layer for Android'. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_Layer_for_Android I assume that's what you are talking about?